# Remove <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="note_list">
  <div class="note">
    Text 1
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text 2  
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text 3  
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text 4  
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="note">
    Text 5  
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Now I would like to use jQuery to *delete* a `<div>` element AFTER the 'X' clicking, is it possible?

First X closes:

```
  <div class="note">
    Text 1
    <a href="">X</a>
  </div>
```

etc etc.
Can I remove a *div* without using `id=""`?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can.... have a look at DOM traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$(".note a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

or instead of `remove()` you could use `slideUp()`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use jQuery's traversal methods to find the correct element. In this case, you just need [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent):

```
$('div.note a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".note a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

u can check here http://jsfiddle.net/3JCR7/1/