# Remove selected item (not inside option field) using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a List of menus which looks like below image those values are bound from DB if I select any one of the item it should delete that element. How do I do that?

[image]

This is my jquery code

```
$.get(url, function (d) {
  self.dt = [];
  self.firmData = JSON.parse(d.Data);
  self.firmData.forEach(function (data) {
  $("#itemlists").append("<div class='item'>" + data.DisplayName + "</div>");
  self.dt.push(data.DisplayName);
   });
 });
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="active content menu scrollbar" style="max-height:365px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="itemlists" style="z-index:999" class="ui divided selection list">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now those values are coming from api if I select any one of the item and try to remove it. It is removing all items I want to remove it only selected item. How do I do that?

**EDIT**

```
    "click #itemlists .item": function (e) {
         var text = $(e.target).text()
         $(this).remove();
    },
```

> I tried using this above method but this is removing all items as well

Comment: Google it: `Remove div jquery` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820191/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820191/3710490)

Comment: If the purpose is to delete it from the *database*, then you need server-sided code. It is not clear what you are asking. Also, where is the code you have a *problem* with? The code you added is not dealing with deletion at all...

Comment: I tried using $(this).remove() function but it is removing all items not that particular selected item

Comment: No not from DB @trincot not permanently delete after refreshing the page it should show that agi

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that attempts to delete an item, including the (click?) event handler.

Comment: check it now... i tried above code but its not working as i expected

Comment: Where ends your forEach in the ajax call?

Comment: it will push the values which i had shown in my question image

Comment: Ok, but there is something missing there... where you close it?

Comment: oops sorry... i didn't end it properly check it now

Answer (score 0):

when click class='item' elements then it will be removed.

```
$(".item").on( "click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is removing all other items as well no that particular selected item

Comment: i wrote only i showed, if you select spesific are you can use like this; $("special_are").find(".item")

Comment: what is the special_are i didn't understand

Comment: <div class="active content menu scrollbar" style="max-height:365px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="itemlists" style="z-index:999" class="ui divided selection list">
    </div>
</div>

this is your special area , that mean that function triggered only clicked in this area . 

$(".content.menu").find(".item").on( "click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});

Answer (score 0):

First i am recording the selected text

```
var text = $(selectedOpts).val();
```

> and then filtering the data from `this.data` and passing it to variable  removeItem

```
const removeItem = value => this.data.filter(item => item.columnsexpo != value)
```

> Now i am assigning the value to `this.data` as

```
this.data = removeItem(text)
```

> Now this.data contains removed item and display only the data which we needed

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram is this ok now??