# How to completely remove div onclick with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

There are some similar questions however my specific problem is an error in my code. I am able to remove the jumbotron div but there is a portion of it that still shows and I'm unsure why.

Here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dominiconorton/2bdxvrwq/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blank</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blank <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
    </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Sign out</button>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Search tutorial -->
<div class="jumbotron" id="searchTutorial">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit 
        </p>

    <div class="removeDiv">
    <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " href="#" role="button">Close tutorial</a>
    </p>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
// close jumbotron //
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.removeDiv').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 and JQuery 3.3.1

I tried changing the parent of the div so that the #searchTutorial is the parent and this didn't work as expected

I would like to completely remove the jumbotron div onclick of the close tutorial

Comment: Why not use `$('.jumbotron').remove()`? Are there other `.jumbotron` elements on the page? If so, try `$(this).closest('.jumbotron').remove()`. https://jsfiddle.net/mdbpu7x9/

Comment: The element to remove has an ID... you should just use `$('#searchTutorial').remove();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove <div> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820162/remove-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Agree with @skyline3000 - I just quickly glanced over the ID. Certainly would make it easier to just select the single element you want removed, and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is removing the direct parent of the div being clicked, which is actually `div.container`.  This isn't obvious because the indenting isn't consistent.

I would actually do @mark.hch's idea and use `$(this).closest('.jumbotron').remove()`.

If you can change the structure, you might consider using `<section>` instead of `<div>` for the major elements, so that you can use `$(this).closest('section').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the class

```
jQuery(function($) {$('.removeDiv a').on('click', function() {$('.jumbotron').remove();});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent of removeDiv is the container div and it's working as expected on click on remove div it removes its parent not the whole jumbotron div, that's why there is gray area appears after removing the container div, so in your case you have to directly select jumbotron div or select parent of parent.